# SQL Developer: View only permissions

Tags: permissions, select, oracle-sql-developer

I am using SQL Developer, generally to assist in writing reports against various databases but there is one application that is run on an annual basis and at the end of that processing (about a 3 hour window) I use FME to further process the records that were added during that time frame. I am limited to view only permissions on the Oracle table(s) and that is all I really need to do my job.

There is a CRM who insists that during that 3 hour window when this particular application is being used by customers outside the organization no one within the organization should access any other parts of the application or any associated database tables. Not for any technical reason, I understand, but because the CRM is afraid that somehow using the tables during that time frame (customers outside the organization are uploading data during that 3 hour window) will somehow potentially cause a problem for the customers.

Recently, in order to get a general idea of the number of records I would later be processing, I ran a small `SELECT` query.  Unfortunately, I inadvertently ran it at the tail-end of the 3 hour window, a little while before the black-out period was scheduled to end.

Apparently, the CRM had advised the DBA to report if anyone internally accesses the database during the applications 3 hour window. The CRM ended up at my desk screaming that no one within the organization was to be using the database in any capacity during the applications 3 hour window.

My questions are the following:
Does running a `SELECT` query on a view only table interfere with any other processes that might be updating the tables in a database?
Or is the CRM being overly cautious?

The CRM is apparently lobbying for me to be written up for this transgression.  So I am looking for some technical information to support my defense.

Comment: @pmdba Could yo please post your comment as an answer? Thanks. If you think it doesn't contain enough information, then you can post it as a community wiki and the community can add more details. The advantage? You earn a community wiki badge and the community has an actual answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Define "cause a problem"... Will running a query affect the data in any way? No. That is literally what Oracle is designed to do: allow queries and transactions to occur simultaneously.

What it *might* do is affect performance of the system, especially if compute resources are tight. Users could possibly experience a slower response time.

That said, your DBA should be able to determine if your actions had any real consequence or risk to your particular system (especially if they're savvy enough to audit your session), or if there is any merit to the CRM's fears.